# Get the text in a grandparent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

I'm trying to modify this function to get the text from the grandparent element

```
span.html(checked.map(function () { return $(this).parent().text(); }).get().join());
```

Both of these functions are returning the grandparent text as well as the text in it's sibling element (`<div class=CheckMark>`). How can I modify it to only return the text from the grandparent element?

```
span.html(checked.map(function () { return $(this).parent().parent().text(); }).get().join());

span.html(checked.map(function () { return $(this).parents(':eq(1)').text(); }).get().join());
```

HTML

```
<li><a href="#">
    <label onclick="toggle_colorbox_alt(this.children[0]);">
        <div style="background-color: #000000" class="color">
            <div class=CheckMark>&#10003;</div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="value" class="cbx"/>
        </div>
        Text I Want
    </label>
</a></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want to get the text of the `label` excluding its children.

You can do this :

```
var p = $(this).closest('label').clone();
p.children().remove();
var txt = p.text();
```

Or in a shorter chained way :

```
var txt = $(this).closest('label').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/eyowik/2/edit)

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to combine it with the function? I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work

Comment: @ChayaCooper See the linked fiddle. I tried to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: Thank you :-D One question - The function is displaying the joined values slightly differently now (without spaces). Do you know what would have affected that? I replaced "$(this).parent().text();" in my function with "$(this).closest('label').clone().children().remove().end().text();"